# Bootstrap dropdown not working in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to learn Angular using bootstrap, but I have a problem concerning bootstrap dropdown element. It doesn't work at all. I've read through all the bugfixes I could find on Stack Overflow but none fixed my issue.

the concerned part of html :

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Events
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Angular Connect</a>
          </div>
        </li>
```

concerned part of angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

- I've already checked and all files are in the right directory
- I've added popper.js to test a solution but it doesn't change anything

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION :**
Add link for js, jquery AND css in index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgFundamentals</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container">
  <events-app></events-app>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this isn't perfect since it's not using the package manager. Just a temporary solution.

I don't know if anything else is of interest.
Thanks already !

Comment: can you try to put them inside index.html ?

Comment: Is only the dropdown not working or can you not use bootstrap styles at all?

Comment: The bootstrap styles are working. I've tried to add it in the index.html it doesn't seems to work (gonna edit my post above)

Comment: I can't see bootsrap css in index.html

Comment: Since bootstrap styles worked i didn't think it was necessary but it worked ! thanks a lot ! (Can you post your solution as an answer so I can mark this subject as resolved ?)

Comment: You might want to consider using ng-bootstrap for your project. This way you don't have to import jquery, see https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples for more info

Answer (score 3):

You said but i think your false directory.Must be like this

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "scss/style.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js"
],
enter code here
```

There must be two dot in front ot the node_modules.
İf you wanna sure.Please click the file and drag drop index.html.You will see truth directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response ^^ I've tried it and it changes nothing :/.